# R Shiny aggregate data from renderUI checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have four `checkboxGroupInput()` widgets, for simplicity A-D. Right now, all four are rendered in the UI, but B is hidden with `shinyjs::hidden()`. In the server, I unhide B dynamically in response to selections in A.

My problem has to do with pulling selections from A and B into one data.frame and C and D into another data.frame when the user hits the submit button. It's doing something I don't understand with the selections from A and B.

Here is my MWE.

```
choices <- letters[1:4]
```

UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  textInput("obj", "Object ID", value=""),
  checkboxGroupInput("A", "Atr A", choices, multiple=TRUE),
  shinyjs::hidden(div(id="dB", checkboxGroupInput("B", "Atr B", choice, multiple=TRUE),
  checkboxGroupInput("C", "Atr C", choices, multiple=TRUE),      
  checkboxGroupInput("D", "Atr D", choices, multiple=TRUE),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit", class = "btn-primary"))
  )
```

Server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Hide/Unhide B
  observeEvent(input$A, ignoreNULL = F,
        {if("a" %in% input$A) {shinyjs::show("dB")
          } else {shinyjs::hide("dB")}
          })

  # Aggregate all form data
  fields <- c("obj","A","B","C","D")
  formData <- reactive({
                       data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
                       data
                     })
  # Save data
  saveData <- function(data) {
    x <- c(data$A, data$B)
    x <- ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x) # fill NAs if no selection made
    x <- data.frame("obj"=rep(data$obj, length(x)), "AB"=x)
    y <- c(data$C, data$D)
    y <- ifelse(is.null(y), NA, y)
    y <- data.frame("obj"=rep(data$obj, length(y)), "CD"=y)
    save(x,y, file="data.RData")
    }

  # Action to take when submit button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$submit, {saveData(formData())}
}
```

Note: if instead of building the data.frames in the `saveData()` function, I simply save the aggregated data:

```
saveData <- function(data){save(data, file="test.RData")}
```

I get an RData file with four objects, A-D, that consist of vectors of characters. I can then build the data.frames there in the way I intended in the `saveData()` function, which makes sense. But, if I run the app with the initial `saveData()` function, the data.frames are different, x containing only one row even when there are multiple selections in A and B.

I have scoured the web, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
choices <- letters[1:4]

ui <- fluidPage(
       shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
       checkboxGroupInput("A", "A Variables:", choices),
       shinyjs::hidden(div(id="dB", checkboxGroupInput("B", "B Varaibles:", choices))),
                  checkboxGroupInput("C", "C Varaibles:", choices)  ,    
                  checkboxGroupInput("D", "D Varaibles:", choices),
                  actionButton("submit", "Submit", class = "btn-primary"),

       textOutput("txt")  #To check the output before it saved

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   # Hide/Unhide B
   observeEvent(input$A, ignoreNULL = F,
           {if("a" %in% input$A) {shinyjs::show("dB")
           } else {shinyjs::hide("dB")}
           })

   # Aggregate all form data
    fields <- c("A","B","C","D")
     formData <- reactive({

        data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]],simplify = F)
        data
})

 output$txt <- renderPrint({ formData() })

# Save data
  saveData <- function(data) {
#x <- cbind(data$A, data$B)
x <- data.frame(A = data$A,B=data$B)
#y <- cbind(data$C, data$D)
y <- data.frame(C=data$C, D=data$D )
save(x,y, file="data.RData")
 }

 # Action to take when submit button is pressed
 observeEvent(input$submit, {saveData(formData())})
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is your WE after some modifications. However, I'm not sure if that what you expected as output. I hope it helps.

Comment: The UI provides a framework for data entry, so I don't need to render user selections there, just save them to an .RData file. The problem I'm running into now is that the data.frame, x, consisting of A and B, only includes the first selection in A, and nothing in B. I thought `x <- c(data$A, data$B)` would handle that, but no luck. So, I'm wondering if maybe the div wrapper or something is changing how the aggregate function stores the data.

Comment: Updated solution will save 2 df with two columns, but columns in each df must be the same length. I remember I read in some place that you can create df with different columns length but I can't remember where. I will try to check. Finally if you have multiple choices questions may be it's better to try save them as 0,1.

Comment: In an earlier iteration, I did use multiple columns, and to deal with columns of different length, I used the workaround `cbind.fill`. However, I figured for data storage and later analysis, it would be easier simply to repeat rows. Hence, the `rep()` function -- now added -- and why I rely on `c()`.